# Don't take reputation away when a question is deleted

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, deleted-questions

It seems unnecessary to take hard-earned reputation away when a question is deleted. If users upvoted for an answer, the one that provided the answer should be able to keep the points, even if the question is removed. Taking the rep away is a disincentive to answer questions in the future.

Comment: Solution: don't answer questions that are likely to get deleted.

Comment: Depends if you answered very poor questions... Those go to the dust bin quickly, so goodbye rep.

Comment: Have you a specific case where this happened to you that sparked this question?

Comment: @Cupcake:  There is no way to know whether a question is going to get deleted or not.  brasofilio:  If a user liked the answer and voted it up what difference does the quality of the question make?   Martin Smith:  That has happened to me more than once.  There's nothing worse than spending 20 minutes on a good answer and seeing the rep disappear because of the question being deleted.

Comment: Related: [Can we please clear misunderstanding that deleting old highly upvoted posts causes reputation loss?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290370/can-we-please-clear-misunderstanding-that-deleting-old-highly-upvoted-posts-caus)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Our reputation score is tied to our contributions on the site, and as a general rule, when we come across a person who has a certain score, we can be confident in knowing that said person has contributed *lasting* and *enduring* contributions to the site that will last for years to come, helping many other visitors with the same problem who find the question and answers from search engines.

If a post is deleted, then it means the community didn't find those contributions valuable; as a result, reputation gained (as well as reputation lost) disappears.

While there's a huge amount of gamification involved in Stack Overflow, the goal is to create a resource of knowledge that helps future visitors for years to come. A site that allows reputation scores to increase for contributions that aren't lasting would be contrary to the spirit of these goals.  Every badge, reputation score increase, and score decrease is engineered to encourage community members to exercise behaviors that support this goal.  Allowing reputation to stick around when the contributions do not would encourage the wrong behaviors.

In the future, if we see posts that don't fit the spirit of Stack Overflow, we should flag them for moderator attention. Or if we have at least 3,000 reputation, we should vote to close the post and move on. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 14):

This is not always the case, it depends greatly on the post itself.  There are more details in the MSE post [Deleted posts should not influence reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124754/deleted-posts-should-not-influence-reputation) and in the blog post [Reputation and Historical Archives](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)

To summarize, Reputation is **not** removed when a post is deleted when:

- It has a score of 3 or greater
- It was visible on the site for at least 60 days

This means the rep earned from any post that the community deems valuable enough to keep around for at least 60 days and has found valuable enough to have a net score of 3 (i.e. `number of upvotes - number of downvotes >= 3`) will not be removed.

If it doesn't meet both criteria, then it will be removed. If a post is deleted in less than 60 days or doesn't achieve the minimum score isn't considered a valuable enough contribution to the site that the owner should keep the reputation.

So you might say

> Why should I be penalized if my good answer (with a score of 3 or more) to a question gets deleted because the question is deleted.

The argument there is exactly what @Cupcake said in the first [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257877/dont-take-rep-points-away-when-a-question-is-deleted#comment33072_257877)

> Solution: don't answer questions that are likely to get deleted

If a question is of poor quality then you should be moderating the question appropriately, that is voting to close, editing, asking clarifying questions in comments, and/or downvoting, not answering.  Poor quality questions are likely to get deleted, either by the automated cleanup scripts or by 10K users or moderators.

Answer (score 7):

I think it is *meant* to be a disincentive to answer particular kinds of questions in the future. If a question is good and unlikely to be deleted, you can keep your hard-earned rep points. If you race the clock to answer a lousy question before it gets closed, how much are you really contributing to the site with that?

Comment: Be interesting to know what the reversal badge is supposed to be incentivising. That rewards good answers to poor questions.

Comment: @Chuck: That would make sense if the questions were deleted right away.  In many cases they may not get deleted for a period of days.  Not exactly a "race to answer a lousy question"

Comment: 'right away' is a relative term.  there is a period of time after which you dont loose the rep.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy: They're deleted after a period of days, but usually questions will get closed sooner than that. I should have said "closed".