# Deleting an answer and the effects on my reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-answers

Does deleting my answer to a question affect my reputation points?

If it does affect my reputation points, how much?

Comment: related... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257877/dont-take-reputation-away-when-a-question-is-deleted/257879#257879

Comment: duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Answer (score 27):

If the post is older than 60 days and has a score of +3 or greater then the post owner gets to keep the net reputation they earned from the post.

In all other cases positive reputation is lost and negative reputation returned when a post is deleted. This includes the -1 to the downvoter as well as the -2 to the recipient of the down-vote. This is worth remembering as it means that you don't necessarily permanently lose the reputation you used to down-vote an answer.

For downvotes on an answer, the downvoter gets their -1 back when the answer is deleted regardless of the answer's age.

Comment: Can I ask the purpose of the last paragraph, which was added two days ago? It seems redundant with the preexisting statement, “In all other cases positive reputation is lost and negative reputation returned when a post is deleted. This includes the -1 to the downvoter as well as the -2 to the recipient of the down-vote.” Am I missing a nuance here?

Answer (score 0):

It does, unless post is older than 60 days. It reverses rep earned or lost by votes .

Comment: well, sometimes.

Comment: Or refunds reputation lost by downvotes.

Comment: And only within a certain time period.

Comment: @Oded by up votes too. I tested. And I remembered about time period but can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @nicael see the link above I posted