# Can I ask for help finding a question in order to avoid posting a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

I understand that Stack Overflow is a database of questions and one should look to see if their particular question has already been asked. What if a user genuinely looks but cannot find the question? Is there a way to ask others IF they know of this question already being asked?

I posted a question [What does this ampersand mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370797/what-does-this-ampersand-mean-in-c) and it was marked as a duplicate. I honestly searched for this question, but I could not find it, so I asked and got a bunch of downvotes.

Even on this meta, [deleting answer and the effects on my reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261698/deleting-answer-and-the-effects-on-my-reputation), it was called a duplicate yet I searched for this question. How people title their question varies greatly and makes finding duplicate questions tougher.

Is there a way to ask if a question is a duplicate without having reputation affected? Some people down vote answers to duplicate questions because it "encourages duplicate questions", but why not help lead people to their question/answer? Could this be a feature added to Stack Overflow?

Comment: Asking a duplicate question is not in and of itself a bad thing. You got some downvotes for that question because it's of the ["general reference"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason) type, and as Hot Licks pointed out there, some people probably thought that you didn't do your homework before asking it.

Comment: That is kind of what I mean though, I tried to do my homework. I did not even know that the '&' was an operator (because I have never used it), so I would have never found the duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276706/what-are-bitwise-operators .

Comment: Who is to say if something is trivial? Just because someone doesn't know how to concatenate a string means that the SO community should punish them? Is SO not for new programmers? If not, is there a place they can go? I think finding the points in a circle is trivial (and non-programming related), yet the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300938/calculating-the-position-of-points-in-a-circle yields 21 upvotes.

Comment: @TheBlindSpring I assume that question got a lot of upvotes because it was relevant and interesting for the people who monitor those particular tags; ie maths, trigonometry and so on.  In that space, it obviously appears to be a valid and specific question.  It would put me to sleep, but it's not a topic I have any interest in :)

Comment: It's not a problem if they don't even mention programming or a programming language?

Comment: If you reasearch your question, put the neccessary time in to reread it and double-check formatting, are responsive to criticism and pointers, it actually doesn't matter all that much whether you wrote a dupe. Worst case you'll get a few downvotes, but you'll also get a pointer in the right direction and will have a better question next time. A few downvoted questions are not the end.

Comment: @TheBlindSpring The tags are *specifically* about algorithms, maths and trig.  These are programming language agnostic and the question was on topic for those tags.

Comment: It seems as though whether a question is well received or not depends on when it is posted and who looks at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789232/find-point-on-circle-on-android is a much better formatted question IMHO (with much less attention paid to it).

Comment: Maybe they just didn't like the poster's hand drawn arrows :)  It also could be that the interest in the other post was to the algorithm tag.  Who can say?

Comment: The fifth and sixth results of [a Google for "c ampersand"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SXkbf.png) would have answered your question, as would a look at [a table of C operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B).

Comment: *Just because someone doesn't know how to concatenate a string means that the SO community should punish them?*. They are not punishing **you**, they are downvoting **the question**. The idea is not to separate goodies from baddies, but to say "this is a good question for SO" or not. Sure, it is true that [the only bad simple question is a duplicate simple question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/podcast-58/), but if your question is extremely basic and easy to answer using Google you should expect downvotes, as unfair as that may seem.

Comment: It's interesting that a Google search for just "c &" is enough to turn up [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) as the first result!

Comment: @Olly funny that here the first link was a local store page, lol. Edit: http://www.c-and-a.com/uk/en/corporate/fashion/ there you go! :D

Comment: @HugoRocha - As a Brit in NY, I should have guessed that C&A would come up first back home!

Comment: Honestly, I never search stackoverflow directly (some of the best answers to questions I didn't know I wanted to ask have come from programming blogs brought to my attention by an unrelated google search).  If you are only searching on stackoverflow, you are limiting the answers you can find and biasing those answers to ones that fit the Q&A format.  You are much better off doing a google search and favoring results that are on stackoverflow. If after searching on google you can't find any viable answers to your question THEN post a question (and not doing a google search WILL earn downvotes).

Comment: Before answering a question, I usually look at the reputation level of the person.  That gives me a better idea as to whether they understand SO, and if they do, they have usually done their research.  I will typically cut a lot more slack for those people, and certainly not downvote a similar (but not identical) question.

Comment: @SableFoste Funny, for me it is exactly the other way around, I cut a new user more slack than someone who has been using SO for a longer time / already has gathered some rep.

Comment: One thing to do is to actually look at the list of suggested matches when you're editing the question in the first place.  I find whatever search engine is used for that works better than simply searching with the search line.  (But, of course, just about anything works better than that search line.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would suggest going to the chatrooms and asking there, particularly if there is a specific chatroom to your domain (say, the C++ or Java or R chatrooms are all very popular and typically can pretty quickly point you to questions, if it's something someone knows off the top of their heads).

You can also look at the tag wiki; major tags, like [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) for example, have lists of commonly asked questions ("canonical" questions) that you can peruse.  In the case of [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), there is a tag [r-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-faq) which is that list.

For [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), this is [the chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54304/c).

Comment: How does one get to the chatrooms?

Comment: Look in the top bar under the StackExchange dropdown.  For your site (StackOverflow for example) select Chat next to it.

Comment: This is a very valuable resource. I am surprised SO does not make this feature more noted and accessible.

Comment: It's on the main dropdown menu, right up top.  Seems pretty notable location to me... :)

Comment: lol, I know where it is now, but I mean without you telling me, where else is chat mentioned? Anywhere?

Comment: @TheBlindSpring: I had never noticed it in the dropdown either. I was just looking for it the other day since people kept mentioning a chat feature, and I had never seen a link to it anywhere. I found it in the grey section at the bottom of the home page. At the top of the grey box, there's a row of links that starts with "help blog chat data".

Comment: It is also mentioned in the sidebar: http://i.imgur.com/36OQPbQ.png

Comment: Very good idea to use the chat rooms. You'll get directly in touch with some lots of experienced people of the given language, who in turn usually don't mind answering what otherwise would have been marked as a duplicate on SO.

Comment: @Seth: Cool, I see that now. That's only on the Meta page, though, not on the main SO page.

Answer (score 20):

The system works if you just ask the duplicate. The result?

10 different wordings and titles all (closed as duplicates) pointing to a single, high quality answer to the question.

It's a powerful system, given enough time. Eventually, nearly any question you could think to ask will have been asked in 10 different ways, so no matter what words you use in your search, you'll find a duplicate pointing to a great answer.

Comment: I think it's important because often 10 different questions all have one answer since unless you know they answer you don't realise they are the same. So it's important to capture all the different manifestations so that people can find the question that is phrased they way they are thinking of it.

Comment: But what about the downvotes?

Comment: @tbodt If it's a well-written duplicate that happens to address the same thing using different wording, I generally haven't seen an issue with downvotes (though I admit, there's probably a correlation between the simplicity of the underlying concept and the number of downvotes). It's the poorly written ones or the "if i pasted the same wording into google i get the older question as the first result" ones that tend to attract the downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

My two cents...

If a question is asked properly, it should not get downvoted. A question should be downvoted only if it is of poor quality.

If the question is a duplicate, it should be closed as a duplicate.

The quality of a question and whether it's a duplicate are two orthogonal properties and should be treated that way. Downvoting a question simply because it is a duplicate is a poor policy.

Answer (score 0):

I personally believe that when I need the answer to some question, I search it up on google. google leads me to **SO**. When google shows me multiple SO links for my search query, I start getting a feeling that there are some duplicate questions (I might be wrong but I am not in most of the cases).

Comment: I think you kind of missed the point. He does search. In the case he was referencing, he *didn't know what to search for*. That's actually a bit common, especially when it comes to different symbols that programming languages use.

Comment: @animuson: that does not mean Ankur missed the point. Perhaps you missed his point. ;-) He just means he is simply patient enough to read the google results and one of them will lead to there. If you can explain what you are looking for, it is chancy you will end up finding the helpful thread. Some patience is needed, indeed, but it will get better over time.

Comment: @animuson it would appear to me that he did search, but only on stackoverflow. IMHO if you are not clear enough on a subject to ask a good question then the Q&A format probably will not help you but google can sometimes work miracles when turning a string of ambiguous gibberish into results.  Also, when someone clearly does not do a google search on what they are trying to ask it throws up flags for me, all of which are negative.