# Losing reputation when removing answer

Tags: discussion, reputation

Let us assume I removed my own answer with 25 upvotes (**edit let us assume this answer was 3 years old**). Am I going to lose a reputation I gained from this answer (250 points) or not? What are the rules? I heard there are bunch of different ones.

Comment: The rule is if the answer is more than 60 days old _and_ has at least 3 score, you keep the rep.

Comment: @Kendra that's a good point! Maybe you will publish that as an answer?

Comment: I'm double checking for duplicates first. I swear this has been asked before, but I may just be thinking of the MSE FAQ post that covers deletions.

Comment: Found the post I was thinking of: [deleting answer and the effects on my reputation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261698/deleting-answer-and-the-effects-on-my-reputation)

Comment: @Kendra I doubt it, but it is possible. I made a look up before I posted.

Comment: That FAQ post I linked should be copied over here. Not everyone thinks to search on meta.SE.

Comment: @Kendra So I self-marked is as duplicate. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Reputation changes from bounties, votes (both up and down), and acceptances on deleted posts (including answers to a deleted question) are nullified. (Exception: Reputation earned for posts with a score of three or higher, and where the post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days, is retained).
>   <sub>From: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/288751)</sub>

Comment: Thanks, I am going to accept this answer in 48 seconds :)