# Why would people want to delete their own upvoted answer?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-answers, upvotes

Why would users delete their answers with upvotes, when they are going to lose reputation?

Examples:

[image]

[image]

Why would they delete?

Comment: I mean I would guess that at 346k and 114k you don't care about the 20 rep gained from the answer so I don't think the rep is a deterrent

Comment: Look at those answerer's reputation. They won't be losing sleep over the lost rep. But: context is king. You didn't provide links to these answers; probably there were other answers that were significantly better, or the exact same solution got posted while these people were still writing theirs. (I have come across both situations and deleted for the same reason.)

Comment: Both of them have comments pointing out some issue with the answer. It could be that each user decided those comments were correct and that the issue outweighed the post's usefulness. The 2nd answer has 6 more comments we can't see; they may have deleted just to end whatever conversation was happening (though less likely).

Comment: That's right, (note i got those two because i got the accepted answers there :D)

Comment: The better question is why some people refuse to delete an answer they know is a bad answer just because it has earned them reputation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Common reasons I know (and used) why to delete own answer:

- I (as author) found that answer does not cover important part of the problem and I don't have time/desire to properly address that. Likely will comment on the question in this case and possibly add comment to the answer (as 10k+ users can see that).
- Someone else provided much better answer (either right at the same time or even way later). At this point it is rarely useful to try to improve my own answer to match quality of the other answer. Especially if my answer is borderline ok but upvoted as the only one at the time.
- Someone commented on or just downvoted my answer and highlighted problems that I can't address (either due to an effort required or lack of knowledge) - I would delete answer if there is another one of reasonable quality.

There are couple things to note

- if you really want that reputation from 3+ upvotes - wait 60 days before deleting ([deleting answer and the effects on my reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261698/deleting-answer-and-the-effects-on-my-reputation)). On other hand if you are not addressing the issue with the question you may get downvotes that hurt much more that even 30 points for upvotes...
- For many people who provide a lot of answers 10-30 points of lost reputation does not mean much and they rather not have low quality answers. People mentioned in the question have 100K+ reputation and probably not too concerned of such loss or even gain nothing from that answer due to daily rep cap. There is no privileges past [20K rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) <sup>*</sup>- so very little reason to worry.
- there are just bad upvotes... Sometimes votes come because "Bob has 100K rep - must be good answer" without even reading (or at least critically reading) the answer. Losing such "upvotes" is not really painful (at least for me).

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>To be precise there are some limits on available votes changing past 20K, but even those max out at 35K - [Privileges > Access To Moderator Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools): "At 10,000 reputation, you can cast 5 delete votes per day. An additional vote is granted per 1000 reputation, to a maximum of 30 delete votes per day.". Thanks [Robert Longson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson) for update.</sub>