# Plagiarism flags should not be automatically cleared when the post is self-deleted

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, plagiarism

As it currently stands, plagiarism flags get automatically cleared by the Community bot when the post — I assume — gets deleted.

This means that **self-deletions silently make these flags go away** even though we obviously don't want them to. Luckily, we already talked about what to do when encountering self-deleted plagiarized posts: [Should self-deleted posts by users who violate rules be flagged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422677/should-self-deleted-posts-by-users-who-violate-rules-be-flagged/423175#423175) (spoiler: for plagiarism yes, they should).

There might be cases where a user posts something, realizes after some time that it violated site rules and proceeds to clean up after themselves. This is good. It's also exceptionally rare.

Since plagiarism is an issue that almost always prompts a more comprehensive investigation of a user's activity on the site, we don't want plagiarism flags to disappear upon self-deletion. Nor upon deletion via votes from non-moderator community members, for that matter.

Please align the behavior of plagiarism flags to that of spam, rude/abusive and custom flags, i.e. to stay active until a moderator explicitly clears them.

---

<sup>[status-review] tag added immediately after post creation as per Community Manager request: we were just discussing this with them at the time of creating this post.</sup>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This bug was resolved; plagiarism flags will no longer automatically disappear upon self-deletion. Thanks for reporting!