When is reputation actually regained from deleting a downvoted answer/question?
According to many posts here (like this accepted answer) you will regain reputation when you delete your downvoted answer to a question.
I just deleted a downvoted answer to test and the score I have is still the same.
When will I receive my lost rep back or has there been any changes to the policy?

Not sure if that's actually the case here, but whenever you "just" did something - wait a while to see indirect effects. Many recalculations take their time and only run every now and then.

@MisterMiyagi when I just downvote I get immediate rep, when I just get upvoted, I get immediate rep. So, deleting your own answer on the other hand depends on recalc?

It can really take a couple of hours. Sometimes I downvote a bad answer, for which I also lose 1 point and even after the answer is deleted it often takes hours until I get the point back.

@IvanPetrov Deleting an answer/question does not add/remove up-/downvotes. It removes the answer/question and the system has to figure out which answers/questions to tally up. Could that be done event-driven? Sure. Is it done event-driven? I wouldn't count on it.

@MisterMiyagi yeah, hence my asking the question. I was under the impression that it doesn't give rep back because of the delay.

Related question: Deleting an answer and the effects on my reputation and especially the "If the post is older than 60 days and has a score of +3 or greater then the post owner gets to keep the net reputation they earned from the post." may apply in some cases.

It is kind of self-sabotage to think in terms of regaining reputation points. You're not really getting lost reputation back, it was never yours to begin with. Your reputation score went down because of downvotes, basic bookkeeping. As a part of a different process, wrapping up deleted content, it may happen that your reputation score increases again. If so, happy days. But there is no hard link between the downvotes causing reputation loss and content deletion causing reputation points to be restored, two different processes entirely.

It’s never really regained. Deleting an answer because it was downvoted isn’t a positive thing. Your deleted answer will always exist, it might be used in the amount of repetition you have,  it it will be considered when it comes to your ability to submit an answer

@Gimby are you really sure or are we just talking here? is this answer wrong?

@MisterMiyagi yeah, I know of this. But that's not what I am asking here.

@SecurityHound for Secret Reasons™, a user with nontrivial contributions is very, very unlikely to receive an answer ban (other than for, say, spam-related reasons).  The quality threshold is...not high.  And deleting a downvoted answer does remove its effects on one's reputation; there's just a delay before the recalculation occurs.

@RyanM - Yes, I am aware it’s unlikely to happen, and I know your reputation is recalculated, but that poorly received answer is still considered and I am extremely disappointed in any user who deletes their own answers before trying to improve them. Sometimes answers just miss the mark, but I see it time and time again, users will delete an answer the moment they receive a downvote. That type reaction is toxic. I also had a typo in my comment. “It might be used…” should have been “it might not be used…”

For some reason I can't find a duplicate target that talks about when rep adjustment from nightly processes occurs, though I know it's been discussed ad nauseum here Meta. The other half of your question is a duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261698/deleting-an-answer-and-the-effects-on-my-reputation

Does this answer your question? Deleting an answer and the effects on my reputation

@TylerH it's not a duplicate. I ask specifically about WHEN, not IF (although as explained in the comments with the delay I wasn't sure for IF too)

@TylerH I would accept jps answer if it was made a bit more official sounding. I can attest that in my case took about 2 hours to get the rep points back.

You asked two questions; the target I suggested is the answer to one of them. I'm sure a question exists on Meta to cover the other question as well, I just can't find it yet. The suggested target is also the more important one (whether rep is refunded is far more important than when).

@TylerH so if there is a question that answers a subquestion of my initial question, does it make the superqustion a duplicate?

It's not a subquestion, it's just another question. And that's the danger of asking multiple questions in one--you risk getting your question closed as a duplicate of one rather than the other, or both. It's also why questions on SO (and Meta) should ask one thing.

Obviously that other question doesn’t answer this one: When is reputation actually regained from deleting a downvoted answer/question? I’ve removed the auxiliary question to avoid distracting from the main question. Feel free to dupe vote with a target that actually answers this one.

@MisterMiyagi thanks for the edit on the behalf of all the people who found my initial question confusing enough to suggest duplicates...

@MisterMiyagi You should not change what is asked--it's OP's prerogative (and responsibility) to do so. In this case it may happily coincide with what OP wanted but you help no one by bending the rules. Obviously that other question doesn't answer the one you mentioned, but it also is obvious that it does answer one of the one's OP asked in their question.

@TylerH Duplicates should answer the question. If another Q&A answers only part of the question, it is not a duplicate. If a question contains multiple questions, the appropriate close reason is lack of focus. The OP has clarified the intention of their question, and edits following the OP's intent are in accordance with the rules. So don’t lecture me on bending the rules when you are the one doing that.

The duplicate target should have this info and be the canonical covering all aspects of deleting an answer, including when the rep is regained.

At some point within the next few hours.  Shouldn't be more than a day.1
For example, in your experiment (in which answer A, answer B, and answer C all have a single downvote and no upvotes, resulting in -2 reputation each), you experienced the following timeline of events:

2024-06-26 07:02:25Z – deleted answer A
2024-06-26 07:03:55Z – undeleted answer A
2024-06-26 07:21:15Z – deleted answer B
2024-06-26 09:25:00Z – reputation recalculated to take all the above into effect, resulting in a gain of +2 reputation
2024-06-26 09:35:08Z – deleted answer C
2024-06-26 09:35:42Z – undeleted answer B
2024-06-26 13:15:00Z – reputation recalculated to take all the above into effect, resulting in no change to reputation

Note that this recalculation timing is not reflected in your reputation history, which backdates changes to the moment of deletion.  The +2 reputation gain is shown occurring at 2024-06-26 09:35:08Z (when answer C was deleted), as that is when the event responsible for the change occurred in the latest recalculation:


1 This is based on my experience as a moderator (including the ability to see when the recalculation actually occurred). I don't know the actual implementation.
