# Impacts of deleting a Question

Tags: support, questions

What effects does deleting a question have?

For example, reputation earned for question, reputation earned by others on answers, flags marked on comments, if question is marked as favorite, reputation for accepted answer. etc.

Comment: Primary effect: The site becomes cleaner

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion L.O.L...L.O.L.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Deleting a question effectively wipes it from the site for users who have under 10k rep.

It is no longer visible or accessible (unless you use an archive or cache of the page) to sub-10k users and all answers and comments are deleted along with the question.

A question can only be deleted by its owner **if** the question has *no upvoted answers*, but a moderator can remove a post at any time for any reason.

All reputation gained from suggested edits and upvotes to the question and its answer(s) [is removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257877/dont-take-reputation-away-when-a-question-is-deleted) unless [it has been on the site for 60 or more days or has a score of at least 3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/258672), in which case reputation changes are permanent.

Flags that contribute to the deletion of the question will be marked as helpful.

Since it effectively disappears, it will no longer appear in the favorite questions list after deletion.

## The good

Noise is removed from the site: poor questions disappear from the front page and low-quality answers are prevented/removed. Deletion is a great way to keep the site clean and tidy; without it, you would likely see a lot more low-quality questions than you do now.

Fortunately, the community is able to handle questions quickly and effectively to rid the site of unnecessary content. The goal of SO (and SE in general) is to provide enduring questions and answers that retain their importance. Deleting bad questions ensures that lasting content is more likely to rise to the top and not be drowned out by the noise.

## The bad

When *you* delete a question, it can have some negative effects. Of course, deleting a question as a reputable user (~1k rep or so) will have little impact, but if, *as a new user*, you delete questions, the system will pick up on suspicious activity and you may receive a question ban if you continue to delete your own downvoted questions to hide your missteps.

Speaking of that, deletion *allows* new users to hide their missteps from sub-10k users because it obscures their history of poor question-asking. However, deletion doesn't hide the questions from the system, which can impose a question ban for over-deletion of downvoted or closed questions.

In fact, a set of new badges was recently introduced to combat poor question-asking: the [Curious](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4127/curious), [Inquisitive](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4128/inquisitive), and [Socratic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4129/socratic) badges reward users for consistently asking well-received questions.

Comment: Thanks! Perfect answer with the good and the bad sections.

Comment: @MandarPandit I'm glad it helped.

Comment: Rep from suggested edits is removed when a question is deleted, not retained.

Comment: @Servy Oh, wow: that's interesting.