# Does deleting a question with 0 votes affect rate limit/question bans?

Tags: support, post-ban, zero-voted-posts

On Stack Overflow, in the beginning of asking a new question, I received a message that warns me that I will be banned for questions, because I have too many not well-received questions.

I can improve my questions, but:

1. my English is not perfect.
2. some questions are short but too complex.
3. some questions have no response, because it is a bug in a product, but nobody has the courage to respond that it is a bug.

So, since improving a questions is not a solution, does deleting a question **with ZERO votes** affect rate limit/question bans?

I have read [Impacts of deleting a Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265587/impacts-of-deleting-a-question), but the response given is not clear relatively to my question.

I have read other questions (more than 10) on this site and sometimes it is written than deleting zero-vote posts has an impact on bans AND sometimes the contrary! I want to be informed before I start deleting some questions to be sure to not be question banned.

The post [Does a zero-vote question affect rate limit/question bans?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328310/does-a-zero-vote-question-affect-rate-limit-question-bans) is not a duplicate, because it doesn't explain DELETION of zero-vote questions, it explains HAVING zero-vote questions ! DELETION is different from HAVING !

Comment: The exact logic for what contributes to a ban is secret, which kind of explains why you find suggestions that are not inline with each other. What ever the actual impact is, a deleted question can't be voted on, improved or answered and is of no benefit to future visitors. In that sense deleting posts (don't care about the score) should be expected to have an effect in calculating if you're close or in a ban.

Comment: Looking at some of your questions on SO proper makes me wonder if they are on-topic. Did you consider if they might better fit on SuperUser or DevOps? If anything, deleting questions that are not on-topic is maybe wise, to prevent that those questions get closed and/or (further)  downvoted.

Comment: wrt the English.it is not as bad as I see in many other posts ...(this is a compliment)

Comment: The most authoritative answer on the topic is here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311810/can-self-censoring-end-up-with-a-question-ban/311812#311812 - does that address your concern?

Comment: thanks to psubsee2003 for his remark. I have read that in 2015, deleting a post without response as no impact on question banning. But is it always the case in 2018 ? In have read some posts where it is explained than deleting a post with negative vote has an impact. In three years, the rules can have been changed ! So my question has always some sense.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: i have added some information to explain that it is not a duplicate

Comment: @rené: what is the difference between SuperUser and StackOverflow ?

Comment: @rené: What is the topic of StackOverflow ? Can you give me some explanations taking some samples in my questions so that I can understand what I do wrong. Thanks for any help.

Comment: @schlebe, please take some time to familiarize yourself with the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). There you'll find what topics are [acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the site. (And some that [aren't](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)). You've been a user for some time, and you probably have some idea about topicality, but reading the actual rules always helps.

Comment: irt scope: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scope

Comment: @yivi: this is the best response that I have (:-) normally I have no response) since I'm on StackOverflow. Thanks very much, I thought since begin that StackOverflow is for any IT questions not only for programming questions. I will then delete my not-in-topic questions here and move them to SuperUser or Devops. Now I understand the remark of René !

Comment: Difference between sites: on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7334/any-guidelines-to-find-the-correct-place and [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: Yes, deleted posts count toward question bans, too

Comment: Hello, I was reviewing your lower scored questions and saw [How can I Paste a local file from Windows Explorer to Thunderbird using Ctrl+V?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350852/how-can-i-paste-a-local-file-from-windows-explorer-to-thunderbird-using-ctrlv) is not on topic for Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is for programming questions, and this is just a question about how to use an application on your computer. By "Programming Questions" we mean questions that have to do with the actual code that makes up a program, which is different from questions about how to use a program.

Comment: @Davy M: I will move it when I have some time and before posting a new question

Comment: @TylerH: you are wrong. That is what the user that has answered to question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311810/can-self-censoring-end-up-with-a-question-ban/311812#311812 say me to say you ! If your are sure of your response why not answering in posting a response and not in posting a comment ?

Comment: @schlebe I'm not sure you understood what I said. I said they count, as in you count them when considering question bans. They don't necessarily automatically *contribute* but you have to take deleted questions into consideration; you can't ignore them. That is what I meant.