# Should we delete the old answers if another user answers with a better solution?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-answers

> Note : Comments from all the answers are now deleted.

So recently [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269037/dan-dascalescu) is commenting on **each and every answer** on this question

[Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/)

> Deleting this answer will help others jump straight to the best
>   content, and you'll keep the points. Thanks!

Now fine that a user has provided a flexbox solution to the question but as a front end developer, I would not go for a flexbox approach because I need to have some support for [Internet Explorer 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8) and [Internet Explorer 9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9) browsers.

Each answer on that question in some way does help users to accomplish their task in some or the other way. If users do not have access to their stylesheets, they can use JavaScript and vice versa.

So the question is why go and comment on every answer and suggest them to delete even if they are not wrong? It just increases the debates and will also confuse future visitors who might think that answer is wrong.

According to me they are different ways to accomplish a particular task. Whether it is easy/optimal or not is upto the users who uses that code. It's like if someone asks how to print a string in [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) so they will get answers where some say use `echo` and some might say use `print` so that doesn't mean you chose the one you like and suggest the rest to delete.

So can we flag a mod or something inorder to prevent the discussion over heavily searched answer? Also some users might feel guilty and delete where this behaviour is wrong and that question might lose some valuable inputs.

> P.S He has also commented on other questions answers for the same
>   thing and recommending more users to delete.

Comment: I read the comments and it seems that this person is arguing over something he should just leave alone... It seems like he is looking to cause a debate over an answer which is unsightly for new and old users... It is not his decision nor right to impose someone delete his/her answers just based on the fact that an answer is already posted...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to feel about this.  He may be *right*, but I feel like he could just create a community wiki answer himself and post the authoritative solution as he sees fit.  Asking people go delete their answers doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: The flexbox answer is accepted, it's already at the top. The comments are pointless.

Comment: I've invited them to this discussion.  At the very least, I'd be curious to hear about the decision to modify an existing answer as opposed to create a new community wiki answer instead.

Comment: @Makoto: I felt the original answerer with the flexbox model deserved the reputation points, so I improved their answer and asked the asker to reconsider the accepted answer. As for posting "the authoritative solution", that's nice in theory, but in practice that answer will stay buried with zero votes for a long while, and the other answers (outdated, limited, or otherwise suboptimal) will keep staying near the top. Keep in mind that when presented with a paradox of choice, most users will default to the first one, and rarely will they investigate all choices.

Comment: @Yannis: I asked others to delete their answers as they saw fit before the correct answer got accepted. Now, my comments asking to delete are indeed less important. Pointless, no, because clutter is clutter.

Comment: @DanDascalescu They are not clutter, you are on a web development answers where sites like Google still uses `bgcolor` even after they are deprecated just to save few bytes

Comment: @Mr. Alien - I had already addressed the IE compatibility problem - use a shim. The comparison between `echo` and `print` is a [weak analogy](http://www.logicallyfallacious.com/index.php/logical-fallacies/182-weak-analogy). Flexbox is a far more powerful and elegant solution than `calc()`, fixed dimensions, JavaScript calculations or other hacks.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Still you are missing the point, we have `:nth-child` pseudos, that doesn't mean users will stop declaring `.last` and `.first` classes if they want to support older browsers, in web we get new thing everyday but unless its not consistent across browsers you cannot use it.

Comment: You can use it with shims. We seem to be debating several points here: browser compatibility, performance (the `bgcolor` hack), and teaching value. I hope we agree that the answer with the most teaching value is the flexbox one. If the other answers are explicitly marked as addressing browser compatibility, performance, or some other aspect, and don't tacitly appear to suggest they express the generally recommended practice, I'm fine with them. The problem is, they're outdated now, and do appear to suggest that JS hacks/fixed dimensions/calc/etc. are the best solution *overall*.

Comment: @DanDascalescu specific Q&A notwithstanding, the point is that you **should not** be telling other users to delete their answers. If they're bad, downvote. If they're **really** bad,  or not answers at all, flag them. If they could be improved, comment or edit. But if they're good answers, even if you don't think that they are the *best* answer, it is **not appropriate** to ask the answerer to delete them.

Comment: @jonrsharpe couldn't have said it better myself

Comment: As a side note, it appears out "perpetrator" has [edited the accepted answer significantly.](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24979148/2). That feels like bad etiquette to me. Sure, the answer is still correct, but shouldn't he just have posted a new answer, and left it at that?

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes we just had the discussion over that in the chat room

Comment: @Mr.Alien: What chat room? I'd like to have a look at the transcript...

Comment: @Cerbrus One of the user pointed out that he had a radical edit on the answer which is not good.. He has also littered the same comments on dupe questions and answers which are now cleaned

Comment: It appears he has a habit of posing his _"This answer is bad, mine is better, please delete it"_ - comment on answers... Flagging some stuff...

Comment: How does deleting one of your own answers mean that "you'll keep the points" ?  That's not been my experience.

Comment: @RobertCrovella There's a set of requirements you have to meet to keep the rep. I believe it's +3 score and older than 60 days. Edit: Yep, found [a source for that.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/257879/2607247)

Comment: @Kendra interesting, thanks for doing the research.

Comment: @Cerbrus yap ...the behaviour kinda pissed me off and even other users, one of the user commented that I should leave my day job and start editing my old answer full time... once the comments were cleaned he edited my answer which said that refer to the selected answer so I don't get why he is emphasizing on that soooooo much

Comment: A plethora of comments telling other people to delete their answers seems like a lot more clutter than alternative answers to a question, in my opinion.

Comment: @starsplusplus: not if those people actually do delete their answers.

Comment: @DanDascalescu - Your behavior could easily be interpreted as nothing but [politicking](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/politicking?s=t). You need to relax and let your answers stand for themselves. Posting an answer and then leaving (rather obnoxious) comments on everyone else's answers isn't going to win you any favors, even if your motives are pure. Leave your answer and if it's useful to other visitors things will work out fine in the end. Crying "censorship" and making a fuss isn't going to help you either.

Comment: I just want to point out that it [appears that someone serial downvoted](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1269037/dan-dascalescu?tab=reputation&sort=post) this guy. Serial downvoting is definitely not the way to go. Please don't serial downvote.

Comment: JDB - it wasn't even *my* answer; it was @Pebbl's. And yes, serial downvoting is what I deserve for trying to reduce clutter on SO.

Comment: @Quincunx: Those votes aren't necessarily all from 1 account, though.

Comment: @Cerbrus - doesn't matter, it's garbage that if someone posts an unpopular opinion on meta that the repercussions are downvotes on questions/answers completely unrelated. It happens every single time.

Comment: Those downvotes aren't the result of your opinion, but your poor attitude.

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't think you're following the conversation, considering the guy being downvoted isn't even the one objecting to the downvoting. And "poor attitude" is *also* not a reason to go downvote somebody's posts.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: when a poor attitude results in poor behaviour, it *is* a good reason to downvote. and yes, the guy being downvoted _is_ the one objecting: _"serial downvoting is what I deserve for trying to reduce clutter on SO"_

Comment: @ChrisHayes I think you're missing his sarcasm

Comment: @Cerbrus If a poor attitude leads to *poor questions and answers*, downvote those poor questions and answers. Don't go downvote perfectly good, valid information because you don't like how somebody behaves in comments. This shouldn't even be an arguable point.

Comment: If a user's being obnoxious to "competing" answers, I'm sure as hell going to downvote his answer. Asking people to delete their answers because your own answer is better, which is what this person did, qualifies as being obnoxious imo. Besides, in the end, people _can_ vote however they like, for whatever reason they like. All I'm saying is, he shouldn't be surprised he got downvoted, with the behavior he's been showing.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Nobody should be telling other users to delete their answers. I understand the point that the commenter was trying to make (that it's desirable for the best answers to be at the top) but that is **not** the way to go about it. Upvote the answers you think are good and rely on the *system* and the community to do what it's supposed to: give the best answers the most votes.

If they're bad, downvote. If they're *really* bad, or not answers at all, flag them. If they could be improved, comment or edit. But if they're good answers, even if you don't think that they are the *best* answer, it is **not appropriate** to ask the answerer to delete them.

In such cases, I would suggest flagging the comments as "Not Constructive".

Comment: All comments now gone and your answer makes sense

Comment: The problem with "rely[ing] on the system and the community to do what it's supposed to: give the best answers the most votes" is that the community doesn't do that. 1. No matter how many upvotes an answer has, the accepted one will be above it ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709/how-do-i-get-the-x-y-pixel-coordinates-of-the-caret-in-text-boxes/22446703)), even if only has one upvote. If the asker is gone, not even mods can change the accepted answer. 2. It can take years for an answer to surpass outdated, but popular ones.

Comment: @DanDascalescu no, you may not (unless the user that raised/moderator that actioned the flags volunteers the information). Comments are "second-class citizens" on SO, they do not have the audit trail that questions and answers do. If one of the answerers wants to delete their answer, there is nothing to stop them.

Comment: @DanDascalescu as for "out of date" answers, this has been addressed elsewhere, see e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252520/3001761

Comment: What do you mean by "If one of the answerers wants to delete their answer, there is nothing to stop them."? How will the answerers know to return to those answers and decide if they want to delete them, if my comments suggesting so have been wiped out?

Comment: @DanDascalescu they may not, but you still shouldn't go around telling people that new answers have been added (not least because you could literally spend your whole day doing that!) If this were desirable, a notification could be added. I think the problem here is that a new question might have been more appropriate than a new answer on such an old question, even one with as high a level of traffic as that.

Comment: @canon true, but I doubt many people favourite all of the questions they answer, or keep track of the notifications

Comment: @canon ah, I see. I meant if we really wanted people to review their answers when new ones were posted, it would be a "red flag" notification at the top of the page, but you're correct that users can already keep track if they're particularly interested.

Comment: @DanDascalescu, this subject has nothing whatsoever to do with "censorship."  It's in both the nature and the rules of StackExchange that stuff gets edited and deleted, opened and closed.  This is not an opressive government suppressing the valid views of citizens with whom it disagrees -- because THAT'S censorship.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Under no circumstances may you suggest another user (and that's especially true with low rep users) to delete their content once *you* think it had been rendered obsolete. You may ping the asker and ask them to change to accepted mark (as I [have in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216115/override-html5-validation#comment45466584_9216115)). You are not to hurt a user's confidence of answering with your personal opinion. Not to mention that a user cannot delete an accepted answer to begin with.

Comment: @Second: that's a mighty strong interdiction. Is there some official policy for it? What if I merely ask the answerer respectfully if they might want to consider updating or deleting their answer in case it has become obsolete?

Comment: @DanDascalescu in terms of *"official policy"*, the (currently) 97 upvotes on this answer are a pretty strong signal that the community is against asking users to delete their answers, even in cases where they've become obsolete. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: @DanDascalescu The only case where an answer to be deleted is if it is completely and utterly trash. That much *is* anchored in policy. Therefore, even when an answer has been rendered obsolete, or if someone posted a better answer, the old one should not be deleted.

Comment: But it's still OK for a user to delete their own answer, right?

Comment: @DanDascalescu we'd rather they didn't delete good answers, but there's nothing (except a rate limit to dissuade rage quitting) to stop them. I believe users can also be disassociated from a Q/A if they want.

Comment: Most of the answers I've seen as *Deleted by owner* were just not that good compared to the answers that had appeared in the meantime, or the answerer realized that the asker was looking for something slightly different and the offered solution was only partial. Or someone else pointed out a flaw their answer exhibited in a corner case, and a better answer emerged meanwhile. Maybe I've been biased by mostly hanging out in the front-end development tags, but very rarely have I seen utterly trash answers deleted by owner.

Comment: @DanDascalescu there's very no benefit to deleting an answer unless it's being actively downvoted, so I can't say that surprises me at all.

Comment: May the answerer in question just doesn't want to lead others astray. Or maybe they want to prevent future downvotes as soon as they realize the answer has a flaw.

Comment: FYI, 99% of automatic flags that we get whenever users hit the daily rate limit for deleting their own answers consists of all 0-score answers - and we ignore pretty much all of them because, let's face it, if the answers were really that great, they would have received at least a couple of upvotes. Users are given permission to self-delete any of their answers except accepted answers for a reason, you know.

Comment: The *only* thing that's being disagreed with here is asking - or even suggesting - to other users that they delete their answers, because it just seems in poor taste regardless of your intentions especially when the community has shown support for it through upvotes. The exception, of course, is when a user has expressed that they want to remove their own answer, and you instruct them to use the delete link to remove it. But you don't tell them "you should remove your answer because X".

Comment: @BoltClock: I see your point. I was just unaware of this strong interdiction against suggesting answer deletion because until now, whenever I occasionally suggested to answerers that deleting outdated answers may be a good idea, they were most often happy to do so.  I saw this as a service to the community - reducing noise, time sink, and potential to lead the user towards a dead end. I would always leave it up to the answerer, of course. Here's an [example from Raynos](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10166574/1269037) on an answer with 20 upvotes (~90k rep). It looks good to me?

Comment: @DanDascalescu in that case, I think it would have been much better to add a line at the start of the answer noting the change (e.g. *"Note that as of v0.6.0 Meteor has direct npm integration, this answer applies only to earlier versions"*); as pointed out elsewhere, there are still users on older technologies for whom this remains useful information.

Comment: @SecondRikudo: was [Roberto's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24171977/1269037) "[utter trash](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286431/should-we-delete-the-old-answers-if-another-user-answers-with-a-better-solution/286439#comment157785_286439)" that it got deleted by Andrew Barber?

Comment: @DanDascalescu Really? You're going to point out things that happened almost a year ago? People make mistakes you know...

Answer (score 25):

Specifically addressing the issue of deleting old answers (and setting aside the debate about commenting) what you said here is key:

> According to me they are different ways to accomplish a particular
>   task. Whether it is easy/optimal or not is upto the users who uses
>   that code.

Some questions have multiple ways of producing a solution. There's a great question out there about finding file ownership in Windows with PHP. The accepted answer only works on word docs. A quick Google search is going to land someone there who might need it on another file type. Fortunately, there are additional answers that have other ways of doing it, even though they are not the 'accepted' answer.

If SO was meant to be a "one question per answer" site the software would have been written to support that - once accepted, answers would no longer be allowed.  The very fact that multiple answers can be submitted for a question (even after one has been submitted) is all the evidence you need to understand that deleting multiple answers on a question goes against the nature of what SO is trying to accomplish.

Comment: +1 It is a *good thing* when a question has multiple answers.

Answer (score 8):

To answer the question in the title: no, do not delete your answer.

Even if two answers say exactly the same thing, they may be understood differently by different people. Maybe one of them will "click" with somebody while the other does not.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer to a question may be incorrect or misleading when new technology comes along. You should update your answer; if you cannot because you don't know a current correct answer or you simply don't want to spend the time, this is when you should delete your answer.

> Deleting this answer will help others jump straight to the best content, and you'll keep the points. Thanks!

No. The voting mechanism is what helps others jump straight to the best content. If an answer does not have a negative vote score, it has provided something useful to the discussion, whether it is the accepted answer or not.

Remember that different answers to the same problem are also possible and while they may not be accepted, they are not necessarily wrong or worse.

Don't delete your answer unless it is providing incorrect information.

Comment: If the old technology is still in use then the answer discussing the old technology is still valid. For example there are still places where IE 6 and IE 7 are still being used or phased out so for those groups an answer supporting old technology would still be useful.

Comment: Yes absolutely. That could fall under the "misleading" part of the statement I made. It would be prudent in these cases to specifically update your answer with a note about the specific version of the system you are referencing.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting your old answers should not be done. But perhaps there is a way to show answers giving priorities to more recent votes/ answers? For instance, for someone to have 10 votes in a month vs 20 votes in a year, the 10 vote question might be a more valuable answer. But it could take years to top the 20 votes that the first answer received, especially as often people only look at the first answer, and don't keep looking.

Alternatively, perhaps a user could de-weight their answer, saying in effect "I don't think this answer is as valuable as others out there", and not have it be shown first.

Answer (score -19):

There is only one circumstance where I would recommend deleting old answers, and that's when the technology changes.  Imagine the following question:

> Can I Foo with Bar?

Last year, the answer might have been something like this:

> No, Bar does not currently support that feature and there's no further suggestion I can offer (other than hacking at the source of Bar yourself, which is beyond the scope of SO, or petitioning the authors of Bar to add it for you).

This year, the answer would look something like this:

> In version 2.0, you can Foo in Bar like this...

In this situation, does the old answer help anyone?  The new answer makes it clear that you need a specific version of Bar in order to perform the desired task.  The old answer *is* just clutter.

**Update**: For everyone who is missing the point here, the number of answers that would be removed by this suggestion is quite small.  Here's a question I answered recently that would qualify.  The OP asks if namespacing exists in Sass.  The answer is no.  There's no suggestion I can offer that would make this work, there is no workaround.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28475907/1652962

Comment: I wouldn't even delete it in that case. Simply leave a comment stating that the solution was for version x.x. Not everyone uses the latest and greatest software, some people are still on IE7!

Comment: Or edit the answer so that instead of saying "does not currently support" it says "as of version 1.99, does not support, "?

Comment: I've been with many companies that takes years to upgrade from one version to another. Even upgrading something like jQuery can take a long, long time. Having access to "obsolete" answers is essential to maintaining existing code. We are not all working in cutting edge technologies. Do not delete an answer unless it is flat out wrong, and only if you know you don't have the expertise to correct it.

Comment: @JDB I'm not suggesting removing answers that contain useful information to users with an older version, only answers that basically boil down to "No" with nothing further to offer when the answer is "Yes, in version X" (see this question next year when the feature being asked about exists:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458017/how-to-work-around-mixins-naming-conflicts).

Comment: I understand what you are suggesting, but even if no version information is given I'm often able to determine the version based on the publish date. So even though version 1 is not specifically mentioned (as it was the only version), seeing last year's date on the answer gives me a pretty good idea that it applies to last year's version. If that happens to be the version I'm using, the answer is very useful (as sometimes happens, the documentation on the service's website may have been updated, giving me misleading info about features that don't exist in my version).

Comment: I agree with this point, though these cases are far and between.  Such answers should be quietly flagged to be obsolete and a moderator will make the proper judgement about whether or not it should be deleted.

Comment: Information about old versions of operating systems and libraries is not obsolete, some people may still be using. Information about an API that is completely discontinued *is* obsolete though.

Comment: I constantly struggle with obsolete technology that I need help with.  Whoever thinks deprecated technology isn't deserving of help via explanations and troubleshooting tips must have an unlimited IT budget with no stakeholders to answer to.

Comment: @Erutan409 Did you even read what I said (including my comment) or did you have a knee jerk reaction like everyone else?

Comment: @cimmanon I did read what you said.  Especially the last part where you refer to old answer as clutter.  That's the part that stuck out to me the most.  Perhaps that part is in need of more elaboration, because to me it came across as those answers of having no value.  However, I would defer to psmears' answer being the most appropriate way of dealing with those scenarios so that you can satisfy both sides of the fence.

Answer (score -23):

If similar practice is any indication, then this question has 5 answers, and 35 deleted ones as they had become obsolete.

[Graph visualization library in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-library-in-javascript/2973499)

On one hand, SO mods only want answers deleted when they're "[completely and utterly trash.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286431/should-we-delete-the-old-answers-if-another-user-answers-with-a-better-solution#comment157785_286439)"

On the other, [question deletions are getting out of hand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50967/question-deletions-are-getting-out-of-hand), but that's okay.

Comment: That's not really an apt comparison, though. Library recommendation questions are off-topic *because* their answers rapidly become obsolete and completely useless (e.g., if a library disappears). In a case like we're discussing here, it's not clear that the old answers lose all of their value. They may not be as good as the accepted or newer answers, but that doesn't make them worthless or deserving of deletion.

Comment: I think you don't get how Stackoverflow works. The op himself writes on his question that this is not ontopic for the website and is retained only because people are heavily searching. That is a suggestion question whereas the one which you commented on is a coding question. A simple thing you should get is that **people don't scrap their iphone 5 if apple releases iphone6** .. I don't have to repeat this for you on every question.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence is not cause to think that this type of reasoning should be applied everywhere.  I don't think it is always a bad idea to delete old answers, but it isn't enough that the answer is obsolete.  It has to be both obsolete *and* providing misinformation as in @cimmanon's example, and even then, it should be flagged quietly and not downvoted.

Comment: @Mr, that's not really an apt comparison, though. Scrapping the iPhone 5 assumes one has it and therefore a sunk cost in it; while asking how to use CSS to do X suggests that the asker hasn't already sunk a cost into a particular solution. Hence my intention of pointing them to the more future-proof one.

Comment: @Mr.Alien actually, not the asker addes this "This question is not on-topic" box, a moderator added it after locking the question. (Also most of the answers were deleted by a moderator.)

Comment: You might benefit from looking at the dates on the posts you just added to your answer... and trash (which includes off-topic) is the reason for voting to delete Q/A, while users can delete their own contributions under far less severe strctures. Also, when cleaning up a question, effectively duplicate answers will often be removed too.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: was [Roberto's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24171977/1269037) "[utter trash](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286431/should-we-delete-the-old-answers-if-another-user-answers-with-a-better-solution/286439#comment157785_286439)" that it got deleted by Andrew Barber?

Comment: @Dan Considering that it's *deleted*, I don't know how you expect me to answer that, or why you're not asking Andrew. Or why you appear to be holding me accountable for somebody else's comment. Did you mean to notify somebody else?

Comment: @ChrisHayes: mostly I intended to [notify Second Rikudo](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286431/should-we-delete-the-old-answers-if-another-user-answers-with-a-better-solution/286508?noredirect=1#comment159253_286439) of an example where an apparently okay answer was deleted without comment by a moderator, which suggests it's not that straightforward to decide that answers should only be deleted when they're "utter trash".