# Should I update very old answers when the solution becomes deprecated?

Tags: support, faq, edits, answers

I have asked a very old question regarding passing variables to the Facebook sharer. The selected answer (which I posted) doesn't work any more and I had someone downvote it. Should I change the answer to the correct way of doing things now or leave it for posterity?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: Having to maintain answers can be painful.  The site is supposed to be collaboratively edited but everybody expects you to keep it current by yourself anyway.  It is up to you, but at a minimum edit the answer and note that it no longer applies today.

Comment: If you know the correct way of doing things now, I'd add it as an edit to the top of the answer. If you don't, I'd at least unaccept the answer to acknowlege that it no longer works.

Comment: I'm not a meta expert, but it seems you should leave the answer as accepted. It was the right answer for your question. Your question was about the product at that point in time.

I don't think anyone should have to comb through all their questions for things that might have improved or more correct ways to do them. You may well no longer even remember how to use that tech anymore. However, since you've been alerted to this by a downvote, edit it in two ways: most importantly change the title to make it clear your question was about an older version. Also put a note at the top of the answer.

Comment: This way, if someone wants to ask a question about the new version, it is clearly a separate question.

Comment: @shannon - note that question about Facebook - there is no "old version" - there is only one current (unlike something like .Net 1, 1.1,2,3,4,5...).

Comment: @Drew you may consider deleting answer altogether unless you want to update it to match the other answer (somewhat strange thing to do) Reputation collected should stay [due to age of the question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/257879/477420)... If you don't want downvotes consider adding something more explicit that it no longer work (and may even mention approximate time range so people maintaining they code can see why they code stopped working).

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You shouldn't change the obsolete answer to a more up-to-date solution because, in general, destructive edits (those that completely change the intended meaning of the post) are discouraged.

The deprecated solution could still be useful to people developing for an old version of the product, even when there is a single version accessible at any given time (e.g. in the case of a web application), for example if they are migrating an old code base.
Furthermore, there might already be a newer answer describing the more up-to-date solution, and the updated answer would then have to compete with it.

You should instead edit the obsolete answer so as to include a note making it clear that, for newer versions of the product, the proposed solution is actually deprecated.

Such note should describe briefly the *exact* procedure that is deprecated, *why* it is so (possibly citing authoritative references), then include a link to the answer with the most up-to-date solution along with a very brief description of the new procedure involved.
If there's no such an answer, you should write it.

Comment: Agreed. Nothing drives me more crazy than working halfway through an answer to realize it's for an obseleted method.  It should be there for previous versions of theproduct (maybe not as important in the FB example, as I'd assume the previous version is no longer available), but it should be clearly marked for current devs

Comment: I think people look at the date on which the question/answer was submited (or at least they should) new versions should be new questions or new answers with relvant version info

Comment: As far as obsolete answers,... well they arent, relatively. Point out that this answer was valid in version n of whatever, and then the answer is never incorrect. There probably is some poor maintenance guy out there somewhere who still has to fix vb6 errors, as in the majority of the real world we dont get to choose which version of software we're using, we can only influence.

Comment: "destructive edits (those which completely change the intended meaning of the post) are not recommended" there's nothing in the help center that says they are destructive. We are recommended to edit posts to clarify the meaning!

Comment: One thing that people tend to forget is that search results will return the questions/answers with most activity/upvotes. That means if you search for a solution you will first find the outdated ones and then you need to navigate yourself to the up-to-date answer. So even when answers are marked with "obsolete" they will still be the first result that pops up.