# Should I approve edits which add warnings that an answer may be invalid?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I'm new to edit reviewing. I ran across an edit that added the line:

> "IMPORTANT: This solution is reported to be not working (anymore?). See comments."

I don't have domain knowledge about the subject, but hit `Approve` on the basis that

1. There is a bit of a problem on SO with outdated "canonical" information sometimes.
2. The reader can decide for themselves if they like the solution, but at least they are warned.
3. It seemed like it may help, but doesn't do harm.

Did I do the "right thing"?

## UPDATE

Sure enough, the edit was approved overall by the community. Based on the feedback from this post, I rolled back the warning statement. Thanks everyone!

Comment: If you don't have domain knowledge to be able to tell if the answer doesn't work, then I would think it's a bad idea to approve this particular edit. You don't know if the warning is correct or not, and it could very well be users who don't fully understand how to work the answer that are saying it doesn't work. I would personally reject this as "conflicting with author's intent". (Note that I don't have the rep to review edits, so I could be completely wrong on my opinions on the matter. Take it with a grain of salt for now.)

Comment: @Kendra I certainly respect your opinion. I wouldn't have asked if I felt 100% right about it.

Comment: Well, for one thing, there should never be anything which says "See comments" in an answer. If there is important information in the comments, it should be in the answer itself. If that doesn't make through review (as I would expect it wouldn't), a new answer could be created with the working code.

Comment: Related: [What should I do if a suggested edit is proposing to update the code to a new version of the language?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308607/what-should-i-do-if-a-suggested-edit-is-proposing-to-update-the-code-to-a-new-ve)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't think this edit should have been approved. Without actually seeing the question, I see a few problems based on how you described it:

**Editor isn't sure if it's working or not**. The edit is very unclear. Does it work or doesn't it? Did it work at one point and it doesn't now? Is the failure due to version updates. There are no details. All we have is "It's reported to not work (maybe?)". At best, we have a warning to be cautious, at worse the edit is completely wrong and the posted solution does still work. A warning like this is going to generate down votes, regardless of whether it's accurate or not.

**See comments.** No. No. No. No. No. Information this important shouldn't be in the comments. If there are details on how to solve the problem in the comments, pull them into another answer. Comments are not meant to hold the important details that solve a problem. They can be removed at any time.

---

If the answer is outdated on a canonical question, there is probably a chat room that can help get the information updated. Several large tags maintain these types of questions and answers to help with their duplicate question targets. Engage the appropriate chat room and see if you can resolve the out dated information in the current answer.

If you can't update the answer without drastically changing what it says, write your own. Utilize the information in the comments to formulate a better, updated, answer. Explain why the current answer doesn't work (anymore?). It sounds like the existing answer already has comments saying it doesn't work, but it may be appropriate to add another stating you've addressed several of these concerns in your new answer.

Comment: thanks for the input. Good learning experience. I think I'll keep an eye on the question and roll back the edit if it gets through.

Comment: The "see comments" part was not about solution to the problem. The comments contain reports that the solution does not work. I answered a question asking about this specific answer not working where I link to a blog post where the author of the original solution states that he is unable to reproduce the intended behavior. I dug through the history of related manpages and found the feature the answer uses has never been documented (and very likely even implemented).

Comment: In the light of facts I stated in my previous comment, I wonder if anything would change about your answer. The edit tried, in a sense, to include the important info from comments in the answer. In a comment regarding the answer we are discussing here, I wrote: "I downvoted it, upvoted the comment that says it doesn’t work, and I recommend anyone who reads this to do the same." Also, I added a link pointing to my answer about this one not working. Do you think anything more should be done? Do you think sharing the specific answer here would be useful? (Guess OP wanted to avoid meta effect.)

Answer (score 9):

## Short answer

Approve: **No**
Reject: **No**
Improve or Skip: **Yes**

## About adding disclaimers

I agree with Kendra's two points that the edit could have been better. However, I don't agree that adding a disclaimer to the top of an answer is wrong.

The [meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175217/is-editing-the-accepted-answer-with-this-answer-is-incorrect-please-downvote-i#comment525156_175218) linked by @justhalf is a good discussion on this. The end result there was "Please downvote" = No, "This answer doesn't work" = Yes. You can see that in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462564/hintpath-on-a-added-reference-in-visual-studio/462650#462650) the disclaimer is still there only editted.

The main points are:

- Comments don't draw enough attention that the answer is wrong (I guess this is in line with Kendra's point that anything relevant should be in the answer)
- You can't rely on the OP to correct the answer as people might not be active anymore
- A new answer will take too long to float to the top (also I don't think you can change your vote on an answer without it being editted first).
- The disclaimer does not change the intent of the OP. It just adds relevant additional information about the answer. I can't imagine it's the OP's intent to knowingly present a non-working answer as if it's a working one.

## About how to act in this case

As I said, I agree with Kendra that the edit could/should've been better, but you shouldn't reject it. This is basically my flow when reviewing:

- The edit improves the original -> **Approve**
- The original post is fine and the edit doesn't improve anything -> **Reject**
- It is a bad edit, but the problem it attempts to address is real ->

  - I can improve the edit (with or without help) -> **Improve it**
  - Otherwise -> **Skip**

I would say in this case you should have probably skipped, unless you were ok with enlisting help in the chatrooms like Kendra suggested (which is a good idea).

Answer (score -13):

@Andy, Kendra, Mike:

> Without actually seeing the question

Perhaps you should have before writing your answer. I'm the editor. I tested the solution, and it definitely **doesn't** work. Other comments, some several years old, say this too, and point to another question with a valid answer and workaround. So it may have worked looong ago, but doesn't for a long time now.

However the answer has many upvotes and is still marked as accepted, but is plainly **not useful**, or **wrong**. All I was trying to do is save readers a tedious test/validate/discard cycle, as I experienced, and try to improve the quality by pointing them to the correct path, which is already there.

A new answer would IMHO **not** work here, as it wouldn't have been read before the reader had (unsuccessfully) tested out the approved answer, and generally be lost among 4 others with low vote counts. Nevertheless I don't want to delete the original content, else the comments would seem displaced and the context of the history lost.

Edit: Allright, I wrapped up the hint into a new answer; still I think the accepted one should show a prominent disclaimer right on top.

Comment: To be clear, I _did_ look at the answer before commenting, and I _do_ feel the edit was completely inappropriate. You should not edit answers to put words in the OPs mouth, which is what this was. Your edit clearly conflicted with the OPs answer. If the answer was incorrect, you can downvote, you can comment, you can do both. But you should _never_ edit to change the meaning of the OPs post.

Comment: @Kendra "You should not edit answers to put words in the OPs mouth" - That's exactly what I avoided by **not** altering the original content, but simply adding a disclaimer. It should be clear to most readers that that part is a newer edit by someone else than the OP. Yes, it does conflict with the answer, because the answer is invalid.

Comment: The answer itself has the OPs name on it, not yours. Sure, it says you edited it, but the OP is shown as the "owner" of the post. You are changing their answer and making it look like they said their answer was wrong. _"should be clear to most readers"_ does _not_ mean that it _will_ be clear to most readers.

Comment: "When should I edit posts? Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged! Some common reasons to edit are: [...] to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages" [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) " If you see something that needs improvement, click edit! [...] To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place" [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). I always thought that's exactly the point of SO...

Comment: @Kendra And, most important to your "because you're not the owner" statement: "Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you." (from the second link). I think you're twisting the intent of SO here.

Comment: From the privileges page, the first link you posted: _"to clarify the meaning of a post **without changing it** (emphasis mine)"_ You changed the meaning of the post, which is _a big no go_ when it comes to editing. There is even a _reject reason_ about changing the author's intent. (Since you seem to so strongly disagree, I urge you to search Meta for questions about editing, see what you can pick up, or even post a question if you still don't feel this is correct. As it stands, your edit conflicted with the community guidelines, whether you believe so or not.)

Comment: @Murphy See [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer?rq=1) for a good discussion of this issue.  Write your own answer and move on.

Comment: I agree with Murphy. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/462650/895932) for an edit by a mod pointing incorrect answer. See the [discussion here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175217/is-editing-the-accepted-answer-with-this-answer-is-incorrect-please-downvote-i), especially the mod's [justifications](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175217/is-editing-the-accepted-answer-with-this-answer-is-incorrect-please-downvote-i#comment525156_175218). Especially since in this case it's not just "a handful of comments" as Tim Medora (in my linked question) objected to.

Comment: I agree that "the accepted one should show a prominent disclaimer right on top", but I don't think it is your responsibility (or right) to put it there. What you could do is bring the post to the attention of the community; ask a new question; research the reason why it appears to work for 100s of people and not for others and make a better, more complete, answer.

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga: It is the community responsibility indeed, and if the author is not active anymore or is not responding to calls to put that disclaimer, then community needs to take action, and it means *someone* in the community needs to do that. We already have a lot of comments explaining why the answer is incorrect, and yet no disclaimer is put, so I believe it's time for community to intervene, to actually put that disclaimer into the answer.