# Is it acceptable to edit answer by giving the newer version of a deprecated function?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

The situation I'm facing is that I came across this [**good** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15368262/5898393) for my project, but using latest Java version and the latest version of the library, two functions used in this answer are deprecated.

To help future readers, I wanted to edit the answer and add this piece of information as an edit. My first action was to see if such an edit is acceptable and I find this [relevant Q/A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308607/what-should-i-do-if-a-suggested-edit-is-proposing-to-update-the-code-to-a-new-ve).

Problem is, [my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18041310) was rejected for the following reason :

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no
>   sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an
>   answer.

My question is then **is such an edit acceptable ? If yes, is my edit does not reflect what I tried to achieve ? Should I have post a new answer instead or was the comment of the user I mention in the edit was enough ?**

What I'm looking for here is improvement for edits in this specific issue but also in a more general way, not to have my edit accepted if it is bad.

Comment: Review just isn't sophisticated enough to accept these kind of edits, the vast majority of the reviewers just don't know anything about the [tag] subject.  Consider what they recommended, add your own answer.

Comment: Better is to write a new answer or leave a comment for the OP to make the adjustments for the newer version/replace the deprecated stuff

Comment: The rules aren't clear for this kind of edits. Some say "maintain content", other say "write your own answer".

Comment: It depends on how the question is asked really. Generally questions don't "upgrade". If a question was about Java 8, then it doesn't automatically become about Java 9 when Java 9 is released and the entire world is not going to instantly switch to Java 9 either; Java 8 will remain relevant for a long time. The fact that something is deprecated in Java 9 then does not really have any meaning to the question. However, it can still be helpful to future readers to have an up to date solution available. Hence: write a new answer and be sure to state the version the answer targets.

Comment: @Tom might be that *maintain content* applies for those with full edit privilege (aka > 2K) and *write your own answer* for anyone else?

Comment: @rene I don't know for sure, might be the case. But then I would wonder what sense this makes. We then have one highly upvoted answer which is maintained and updated and few newer answers which only repeat the older answer when it has been updated. Thus it would only result in more clutter. If a review can't or won't verify the correctness of an edit (apart from styling and spelling), then that person should just skip it.

Comment: When editing, append the new version underneath the old, with an **UPDATE USING: VXX**' header,  leaving the older version unchanged?  That allows both versions under one answer, avoids the clutter of a new Q&A and is less likely to offend the original poster.

Comment: What I'd say personally is make you own answer and explain how it differs from the other answer.

Comment: In the current answer you can add something like "Note: This is for Java 8. In Java 9 the function foobar() is deprecated and barfoo() is used instead.

Comment: Very related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359377/119775

Comment: For the record, I would have chosen "Improve Edit". I think it is sound practice to add relevant new details to a good existing answer that is highly-upvoted, rather than hiding them away in some other answer where they don't even make sense out of context. But I would have removed the "*Edit: ...*" clutter.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the great feedbacks, the consensus tend to agree on posting a new answer with the new information due to language / library updates. But what @Jean-François Corbett said _'add relevant new details to a good existing answer that is highly-upvoted, rather than hiding them away in some other answer where they don't even make sense out of context'_, this is exactly the reason why I made this edit. Adding the 10th answer to this question (question from 2013...) doesn't seem as useful as an edit to the answer everyone will surely read.

Comment: An edit like this could be considered an addendum and would fit with the guidance on [editing posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). By adding alternative code though, you are essentially putting two answers into one post. Perhaps it would be better, as others have pointed out, to edit in a simple notice to mention that the answer is no longer usable in newer versions. This would alert users (at least those that don't just copy and paste code and expect it to work flawlessly) to look elsewhere.

Comment: @fab Well, that's the majority opinion *of those few people who happened to post comments here*, not the consensus of the community. If you look at e.g. [that other question I linked to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359377/119775), the votes on the two options point in the opposite direction, i.e. prefer editing small addenda into the existing answer. So I wouldn't call a consensus just yet.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett Indeed, you're absolutely right, wrong use of word here.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I would recommend posting a new answer highlighting the method to do it in version XY and adding a minor edit in the other answer that just states:

**Note, this answer is for version *(up to)* UY, if you're using XY see *[the answer](http://www.foobar.com)* by *[author](http://www.foobar.com)***

I've seen it used more often and found it very useful. it leaves the original answer relevant for it's own version but provides a direct waypoint to newer software versions.

Comment: This is clearly the way to go here since it reconcile more or less the two point of view on this matter. But I still do have the feeling that a clear rule would help a lot of user & reviewer on this.

Comment: There are no clear rule, there's only the community concensus to go by. that may vary/differ from year to year.

Answer (score 4):

I'd edit the answer and have done so many times, adding a section where appropriate something like: "as of version X the solution has changed to ..."

Writing a new answer feels wrong because it will be buried if there are many answers or if the accepted answer is long. Instead of helping users who come to the question they'll read the now wrong answer and go on their way. Spreading bad or stale information doesn't seem like fits the goals of SO. This is no different than the old problem of googling for an answer on MDSN and finding an outdated and possibly dangerous answer and being expected to some how magically divine the correct answer is somewhere else.

As for comments they can often be buried. If there are no comments then it has a chance of being read by someone looking for an answer. If there are many comments, especially if there are so many that SO is only displaying the highest upvoted ones then comments are effectively useless for informing people seeking answers to get the correct info.