# How to reject an edit that adds code from a 3rd party site?

Tags: discussion, specific-edit

I came across [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76727123/why-am-i-receiving-no-output) where a user wanted to add code from a 3rd party site for the OP via an edit.

Based on the comments, the issue is already resolved, but I then looked around a bit on how to handle such edits, but didn't really find anything specific on it.

In the following posts, one always just mentions “reject”:

- [Edits that add OP's code from 3rd party site where the license is unavailable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348698/edits-that-add-ops-code-from-3rd-party-site-where-the-license-is-unavailable)
- [What should I do if a suggested edit is proposing to update the code to a new version of the language?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308607/what-should-i-do-if-a-suggested-edit-is-proposing-to-update-the-code-to-a-new-ve)

But the selectable reasons are somehow not applicable for me:

[image]

How would you reject this edit or with which of the mentioned reasons?

“*This edit causes harm*”, where you can still write a few lines yourself, sounds a bit drastic to me and the other options are somehow not applicable, if you at least read the small printed descriptions.

Comment: The comments under the question make me think if op has multiple accounts. The asker (a new account from today) wrote "I fixed it thank you for your time if you looked at it. I will put it not in a link next time", but the edit was suggested by another account.

Comment: That edit looks like it's a *good* edit. The user is adding the code from Pastebin which the OP provided a link, however, the code *should* be in the question *not* an off-site resource; if the off-site resource ever becomes unavailable then the question is useless. Moving it from Pastebin to the question is what's needed.

Comment: @ThomA That's what I was confused about. While this looks like a good edit, I was going with the posts linked above. Similar to “*Don't translate text out of images*”, which is only slightly different, I thought the same “rule” would apply here and the OP has to add the code on its own.

Comment: There are no images involved here, @Dominik . There's no concern that a character could be transcribed incorrectly.

Comment: @BDL I think "I fixed it" means “I fixed the problem” instead of “I fixed the link/example".

Comment: @ThomA This was more of a general thing now, not applied to the post linked. While we should not translate text out of images for a good reason, I transitioned this to "Don't add a full code from other websites for the OP" as well.

Comment: @ThomA: When you repost content from some other page to SO, you need to make sure that the license from the original page allows you to repost it on SO under cc-by-sa. Since the linked pastebin doesn't state any license, my guess is that it is not ok since the code is still owned by the original author. Edits that introduce copyrighted material should probably be rejected.

Comment: The reason to not transcribe images is so to not introduce errors, when you copy text you get text so you aren't adding errors

Comment: The licence is in Pastebin's [Terms of Service](https://pastebin.com/doc_terms_of_service), @BDL.

Comment: @Dominik: The reason why you shouldn't transcribe images is because of the high error rate while transcribing; [Famous Case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375127/why-would-someone-reject-this-edit). Many times, errors are removed or additional errors are introduced. This doesn't really apply to copying code.

Comment: @ThomA: I'd interpret section D.5: *"..., but not to otherwise redistribute or republish Your Content outside of the Website or Service without your separate permission"* in a way that you can't repost that content on SO without explicit permission by the author?

Comment: I suppose we then end in a position where is it implied permission, @BDL ; if the user wants an answer then that code needs to be used and therefore implicit permission has been given (it's impossible for answer without it). If they don't, then the code is irrelevant and the link should be removed.

Comment: @BDL Yeah, transcribing images is not a good practice, I learned that myself. Was just wondering if cases are completely different, as the code on the 3rd party site may contain copy & past errors as well. One may take them over to SO as well, or changes have been made to the code in the meantime from the OP.

Comment: If the code on the 3rd party site contains an error, then it's the user that wrote that (presumably the OP) that introduced those, @Dominik, not someone transcribing it or software interpreting it. Knowing what those errors are are important as they are likely the reason the user is asking a question.

Comment: @ThomA: IANAL, but I don't think that it works like that. You can't even guarantee that the person that posted on SO is the same person that created the pastebin. They could be linking to some random persons pastebin that they found and need help with. And even if it would be the same author, at least the law in my country doesn't interfere any "implied" rights from posting a link.

Comment: @ThomA That's *inferred* permission. You are inferring permission where none was explicitly given. That's skating on some legally thin ice. Pastebin would be well within its rights to file a DMCA request to get it taken down. Would they? No. But you can't take permission just because you think that the author would have given it if they had been asked. You have to ask.

Comment: I suppose that means, by your logic @HereticMonkey,  that as the code was provided by a guest user, it can now *never* appear on [so], as there's no way to verify the user, and the code can't be used here.

Comment: @ThomA Perhaps. I don't see how we lost anything of great value. But I'm not a Python developer...

Comment: @ThomA: It means that noone else except the person who posted it on pastebin can move it to SO. In a review, you will never be able to judge that, so I would reject it. If the author of the SO questions adds the pastebin to there question, it's their job to make sure that they have a valid license for the content.