# Why have I been review-banned for two months without receiving any message or notification?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review-suspension

I received NO suspension or other message on Stackoverflow or email explaining what *appears* to be a manual suspension by a diamond mod.

I found my heinous approval of a suggested edit in Review Queues:

> https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23759670
>   Come back on Oct 14 at 15:02 to continue reviewing.

I can clearly see why this was an erroneous review on my part.

Over my 10 years of membership, I've been suspended for short periods of time for failing Audits and from those, I've learned to improve my reviews.  As well, I always go back through the history now to see how my reviews compare with others' to ensure I'm being fair.

What I really want to know is why a simple explanation wasn't provided with the suspension and why the suspension is 2 months.

Comment: If you're suspended it's always over all review queues. If you're doing it wrong in one queue, simply moving on to doing it wrong in another queue isn't helpful behaviour.

Comment: Thank you - memory has failed me there.  Now that that's resolved, I would still like the explanation.

Comment: What exactly do you need explaining? Why that specific suggested edit didn't have to be approved?

Comment: Until this latest suspension, I've always been clearly notified with an explanation, so I expected the same this time.  I can see clearly why the edit in question shouldn't have been approved.  2 months seems excessive.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The accepted answer certainly doesn't apply. We may debate if that edit (removing a solution for software no-one should be using, but some still might be) is a good edit. Changing the link to a version-agnostic one sounds good to me. There's probably a reason a mod got involved and thought a suspension was warranted here (other than spam because the edit is just not spammy), and I'd like to hear it.

Comment: *"see how my reviews compare with others' to ensure I'm being fair"* - Well there's your problem, only a fraction of suggested edit reviewers do a good job

Comment: The proposed edit removes useful information. It's not impossible that someone with no choice but to work on an obsolete version will come across the answer, in which case knowing that this option is not available to them would be beneficial (compared to having to try the code and have it fail).

Comment: I review banned you for all the reasons mentioned in the comments here and the answer here. If I manually review ban someone I make the ban slightly longer than an automatic ban, as it takes so much time to go through and moderate a series of bad edits I want to ensure the reviewers pay attention and don't repeat it. The reviewers are responsible for keeping edits helpful and from stopping people from making trivial edits or changing the original intent of the post. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288987/should-i-update-very-old-answers-when-the-solution-becomes-deprecated

Comment: @ErikA I got involved via a custom mod flag and then being pinged in a chatroom by the editor. The editor was going through very old posts and editing the original intent. They were told not to edit posts in this way and referred to the faq  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288987/should-i-update-very-old-answers-when-the-solution-becomes-deprecated

Comment: When manually banning someone from reviewing it bans the person from all the queues- we have no control over that sorry.

Comment: My question is clearly about **my not being notified** of the ban and the reason.  So this is NOT a duplicate of any other question.  None of the comments or answer addresses that.  So I'm suprised the 1 answer got any votes at all.

Answer (score 13):

Can't speak for the suspension, but that is not an edit that should be approved. The review task you link to, is an example of an edit suggestion that should have been rejected.

The reason is that while the information can apply to older software, that is no reason to remove it. People in the world use software of any age, and it is very much not your responsibility to prevent them from reading pertinent information pertaining to their current situation.

Please do not approve the removal of information simply because a software is outdated, outdated software still exists and real humans need to maintain it for any number of reasons that you have no right to reject.

Comment: Totally agree and there's this to refer people to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288987/should-i-update-very-old-answers-when-the-solution-becomes-deprecated.