# User being removed shouldn't affect rep

Tags: support, reputation

I just lost 80 rep points due to 'user being removed'.

I read the attached article https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed

What counts as a high quality that would result in the user being removed not affecting the rep of others?

To me 80 rep points is quite a large sum of points being removed while to a 60k user it would be a very minimal change.

Furthermore I don't think its fair to remove rep points from the users who are putting the time and effort into providing answers to questions.

Comment: so, if I ask my friends to create accounts, do edits to get the required rep for upvote, and then upvote me to get me rep, but then they get nuked for sock pupetting (or fraudulent votes)... it shouldn't be removed? The page you link to doesn't just say "if the user deletes their account". It talks of "violating the network's terms of services"... that definitely should get whatever vote nuked)

Comment: [Meta dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted)

Comment: @Patrice If that were the instance then I would agree but thats not what happened here and it wasnt 1 but 2 accounts that were removed each resulting in -40 rep points

Comment: @CoderJoe ok..... then if it's 2 sock puppets? You can't know because it's more than one account. And, considering it's an *automated* system... how is the system able to make the difference? Your argument is "this isn't what happened here".... but you can't know that. You can know you didn't ASK for people to do it. Can you know for sure it's still not people who just voted you up blindly, and did little else on the site?

Comment: If really two users were removed who both voted four times on you, then that very much sounds like sockpuppets. Maybe not yours, but someone else's who tried to hide there tracks by doing some random voting.

Comment: It's also not the first time an account who voted on you has been removed. The last time was on March 21th with -115 points.

Comment: Well if it were mine then I would have been banned alongside the other 2 accounts, what I dont understand is how since I have not recieved any rep gain in about a week this just happened

Comment: Is it possible that a mod or someone with a higher rep can find out who the removed users were @BDL

Comment: Mods could probably figure it out, but they shouldn't be telling you; voting records are supposed to be anonymous.  As for why those accounts were deleted now, it's because it takes time for patterns to emerge, especially if they're trying to hide their tracks by voting for other people.

Comment: Would a mod be allowed to tell us the reason why they were removed

Comment: and also what questions/answers were affected

Comment: Related feature request: [Don't take reputation away when a question is deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257877/2675154)

Comment: @CoderJoe - I think you're putting too much stock in reputation. If your answers are good, they will gain reputation organically. Losing it sucks, but its not like you can't just regain it.

Comment: I've seen one person drop 1.5k reputation in a day - this is a drop in the bucket

Comment: If the removed account were fraudulent, what's your argument for retaining the rep gained from their votes? I just don't get it.

Comment: Because I wasnt thinking of it as a fraudulent account... @yivi

Comment: Well, you'll gain the rep again. And hopefully from more lasting users. The only harm is that you lost access to the review queues until you regain the rep. And you were clicking "no action needed" all too often anyway.

Comment: the question doesn't deserve so many downvotes. OP is rather new, and probably didn't imagine the amount of fraud we're dealing with.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre OP posted feature request without "feature-request" tag. That's traditionally good reason to vote as "Best feature I always wanted"/"I don't like that feature suggestion". You are welcome to edit the question into "support" one if it does not look like feature request to you.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov fair enough. The question title _looks_ like a feature request.

Comment: knowing what I know now my question seems rather dumb @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A lot of user removals are due to sockpuppet voting. You wouldn't believe how many fake/fraudulent accounts we remove per week.

So the reputation gained from those account votes *must* be removed, to correct the voting. If it happens that those accounts also voted for you (sometimes a lame strategy to try to fool the moderators -note: it doesn't work-), then the votes are invalidated as well.

Other case is user requesting account deletion. It also happens, more rarely. In the end, the user has been destroyed, and the rep gained from the votes is lost.

Note that when deleting a (non-fraudulent) user with a very high reputation, the community managers can decide to keep reputation from votes of this user, because the vote invalidation would mean that a lot of people would lose a lot of points (statistically, high-reputation users vote a lot all along the numerous years of the account existence)

> Because high-reputation users have usually cast a great many votes, removing all of them could be that much more disruptive to other users. In such cases, the staff use a special deletion that preserves the votes, resulting in no reputation change for those who had been voted on by that user.

Doing that for every non-fraudulent account would be a lot of work I suppose. Well beyond the power of the non-SE employees moderators like me.

Comment: Is there anyway that you can tell weather it was a fradulent account or not?

Comment: Its just odd to me that 2 accounts that voted for me 4 times were removed at the same time

Comment: how can you be sure that the votes come from 2 accounts and not one? you checked the votes on your posts before/after? note that sockpuppets can be more than one. Some users create several to get rep more quickly. When mods find out, they usually delete all the sockpuppets, so if both voted for you, well... too bad. But it's rep you wouldn't have had otherwise. Don't be sad.

Comment: I know it came from 2 different accounts because I have 2 notifications for "user removed"

Comment: "Is there anyway that you can tell whether it was a fradulent account or not? " : obivously not going into details on that sensitive subject. Sorry. Classified :)

Comment: Understandable but I get it, its rep I wouldnt have had anyway so no point harping over it

Comment: @CoderJoe - I removed both of those accounts. While I don't believe you were the direct target of this, those accounts were clearly sock puppets of another user. They may have been using them to boost their natural votes, and you happened to be one beneficiary, but these were not legitimate votes. Given that they should not have been able to do this in the first place, you've really lost nothing here.

Comment: I don't have the full stats (CMs may have them) but the percentage of account removal because of fraud is probably extremely high. I didn't know Brad had removed those accounts, but as you see those were fraudulent.