How to deal with comment that refer to interesting deleted answer?
I found this comment :

"timestamp has a some limitations, you might want to read this stackoverflow.com/a/7229760/2652018"

The link refer to a question that seems similar. The link doesn't seems to refer to specific answer (but should). I check for actual answers, and found another comment of the same person:

"timestamp has some limitations mate, and some bugs too, for example a timestamp can't handle a date before 1970 and after 2038 (see Ivar Koster's answer)"

There is no answer from "Ivar Koster". I searched for the user, and found him but there is nothing on it even if has reputation. It seems they have been inactive since 12 years and hence haven't changed the post themselves (as it was here 10 years ago).
The issue is : A least one of his answer seems interesting, but they are no longer available.
Do you know where this answer is and why it disappear?
Also, how to deal with that type of comment? They seems "No longer needed" as they are outdated, but also necessary as they are preventing from possible issue. And they can't be converted into answer and the real content is in the invisible answer.

There's something odd about that deleted post; the user still has reputation from it. When a post is deleted, the reputation should be reversed; there can be a delay, not not a 4 year delay.

@ThomA it's 6 years old, maybe it's removed only between 2018 and now

As I said, it was deleted 4 years ago.

Just flag as "no longer needed" and move on.

@ThomA Reputation is not always removed when a post is deleted. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/257879/1426539

As a side note that comment is kind of outdated now, you'll only face that issue if you use 32-bit versions of PHP, 64-bit versions have a much bigger range.

@Elikill58 "it showed 0 reputation on search list" you're probably looking at the "week" reputation, if you switch it to "all" it shows their actual reputation.


How to deal with comment that refer to interesting deleted answer?

Flag it as No Longer Needed.

Do you know where this answer is and why it disappear?

Here's the answer in question:

You'd have to ask the moderator, Martijn, why they deleted that answer. However, given that they're no longer a moderator, and deletion happened 4 years ago, they may not have access to that information, or remember why.
I would assume Martijn deleted it because it does not answer the question of How can I check if the current date/time is past a set date/time? which is the question under which it was posted.

Yes, that's possible. It doesn't answer and also doesn't really explain. It's disappointed about this answer

Low quality answers should be downvoted, not manually deleted. But this was a late answer and it is so wildly off the mark that it can hardly be considered an attempt to answer anything while holding a straight face. It reads like a comment posted as an answer. That would be the reason I would personally support manually deleting this.

@Gimby This isn't a low quality answer, though. It's just Not An Answer. And low quality answers should absolutely be delete voted if the author cannot/does not fix them. The VLQ flag for answers says "This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed." (bold emphasis mine). Downvoting doesn't remove posts, only deleting does
